# Python Convert String to Namespace

Tags: python, string, namespaces, integer

I need to figure out a way to convert a string in python to a namespace that can carry an integer value. This is important for a script I'm writing that creates a character sheet for a pen and paper roleplaying game that uses stat adjusted target numbers- I'm writing it in modules, and each stat calls one of these modules using a different version of a name in the same initial string, which is supposed to be converted to a namespace, then used to carry an integer that is used to modify another integer in a class.

Comment: Can you give an example with the code?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__):

```
mod = __import__(name)
print mod.something
```

This allows you to use an arbitrary string `name` as the name of a module to import. You can create a module named for example `foo.py` that contains:

```
something = 4
```

and then the above code will print 4 if `name` is `"foo"`.

This is, however, an uncommon programming technique in Python (as noted in the documentation), so there is probably a better way to express your intent.

Comment: starting with 2.7 you can use importlib
http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning that the above is somewhat different in Python 3.